# Proof of similarity between well ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Naive Set Theory* we have a proof that two well ordered sets are either similar to one another or one of them is similar to an initial segment of the other.

It goes like this:

> We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty well ordered sets such that neither is similar to an initial segment of the other; we proceed to prove that under these circumstances $X$ must be similar to $Y$. Suppose that $a \in X$ and that $t$ is a sequence of type $a$ in $Y$; in other words $t$ is a function from $s(a)$ into $Y$. Let $f(t)$ be the least of the proper upper bounds of the range of $t$ in $Y$, if there are any; in the contrary case, let $f(t)$ be the least element of $Y$. In the terminology of the transfinite recursion theorem, the function $f$ thereby determined is a sequence function of type $X$ in $Y$. Let $U$ be the function that the transfinite recursion theorem associates with this situation. An easy argument (by transfinite induction) shows that, for each $z$ in $X$, the function $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$. This implies that $U$ is a similarity, and the proof is complete.

My questions are:

> 1. Is the hypothesis of *neither set being similar to an initial segment of the other* used implicitly in some way inside the proof or, simply, it just doesn't get in the way of the conclusion?
> 2. What is it about $z$?

In case the terminology is not clear:

A *sequence of type $a$ in $Y$* is a function from the initial segment of $a$ in $X$ into $Y$; A *sequence function of type $X$ in $Y$* is a function whose domain consists of all sequences of type $a$ in $Y$, for all elements $a$ in $X$.

Comment: Wow. It's impossible for me to understand without opening the book, which I don't have. Indeed it's hard to be thorough and naive... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second question first, $z$ appears to be a typo for $a$.

The hypothesis of neither set being similar to an initial segment of the other is essential. If $X$ were similar to an initial segment of $Y$, you could still construct the function $U$, and it would still be one-to-one, but it would not map $X$ **onto** $Y$. If $Y$ were similar to an initial segment of $X$, you’d have an $a\in X$ such that $Y$ has no sequence of type $a$.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that. Thank you very much!

Comment: As for $z$, I also thought it should be a typo. But you never know...

Comment: @Fred: You’re welcome! (Yes, that kind of typo is a bit nerve-wracking.)

Comment: Late correction to this answer: the hypothesis that $Y$ is not similar to an initial segment of $X$ is not needed for the existence of sequences of type $a$ - there are always these as long as $Y$ is non-empty, as constant sequences are allowed. The hypothesis is actually used to show that $U$ is injective / one-to-one, so that at no point does $Y$ "run out" and cause $U$ to start generating the least element of $Y$ again.