# Prove the comparability theorem for well ordered sets using transfinite induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, well-orders

My question is about the same proof discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305892/proof-of-similarity-between-well-ordered-sets), but I am confused about more than this question addresses.

In *Naive Set Theory*, Halmos phrases the comparability theorem as follows:

> The assertion is that if $\langle X, \leqslant_X \rangle$ and $\langle Y, \leqslant_Y \rangle$ are well ordered sets, then either $X$ and $Y$ are similar, or one of them is similar to an initial segment of the other.

My questions are about the following proof:

> We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty well ordered sets such that neither is similar to an initial segment of the other; we proceed to prove that under these circumstances $X$ must be similar to $Y$. Suppose that $a \in X$ and that $t$ is a sequence of type $a$ in $Y$; in other words $t$ is a function from $s(a)$ into $Y$. Let $f(t)$ be the least of the proper upper bounds of the range of $t$ in $Y$, if there are any; in the contrary case, let $f(t)$ be the least element of $Y$. In the terminology of the transfinite recursion theorem, the function $f$ thereby determined is a sequence function of type $X$ in $Y$. Let $U$ be the function that the transfinite recursion theorem associates with this situation. An easy argument (by transfinite induction) shows that, for each $a \in X$, the function $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$. This implies $U$ is a similarity, and the proof is complete.

Where the statement of the transfinite recursion theorem is:

> If $W$ is a well ordered set, and if $f$ is a sequence function of type $W$ in a set $X$, then there exists a unique function $U$ from $W$ into $X$ such that $U(a) = f(U|_{s(a)})$ for each $a$ in $W$.

and $s(a)$ is the initial segment of $a$.

I don't understand how to complete the proof given this outline. My questions are:

1. How do I show that, for each $a \in X$, the function $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$

I can figure out how to set up the beginning of the transfinite induction proof (I think), but can't prove the induction step:

Let $S$ be the set of all $a \in X$ such that $U$ maps the initial segment determined by $a$ in $X$ one-to-one onto the initial segment determined by $U(a)$ in $Y$. Assume by the hypothesis of transfinite induction that the initial segment $s(a) \subseteq S$.

How do I show that $a \in S$?

Finally, given (1),

2. Why is U 1-1?
3. Why is U onto?
4. Why is it the case that $\forall a, b \in X, a \leqslant_X b \iff U(a) \leqslant_Y U(b)$?

I'm really not sure where to even start with these last three. I can write down the definitions of 1-1 and onto and stare at them, and stare at their contrapositives, but I can't figure out how to make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply part of the induction. If $U$ was a bijection between $s(a)$ and $s(y)$, then by the definition, $U(a)$ must be mapped to $\min Y\setminus s(y)$. And that is also injective, and it is also surjective onto $s(U(a))$ because that is the only thing we added. And likewise, it has to remain order preserving for the same reason.

For the limit case, the proof is somewhat similar.

---

If you are not Halmos, and you are not afraid of ordinals, then you can really talk about this as a transfinite induction over *order-types*. Then this becomes clearer from an intuitive point of view.

The initial segments of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, have "shorter" order types, and must therefore embed into one another in the appropriate way.

Comment: I think I understand now why U is a similarity given (1), thanks. Could you expand on how the induction step works? If you know that for all b < a there's a bijection from s(b) to s(U(b)), how do you get a bijection from s(a) to s(U(a))?

Comment: It's not some "random bijection". You explicitly construct that bijection. Try to do it for $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb N$ with the reverse order. It is a very illuminating example.

Comment: Where is the fact that none of $X$ or $Y$ is similar to an initial segment of the other, used?