# Construction of a sequence function in Halmos' proof of the comparability theorem for well ordered sets using transfinite recursion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

The proof mentioned is from *Halmos's Naive Set Theory* and is identical to the one described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001032/prove-the-comparability-theorem-for-well-ordered-sets-using-transfinite-inductio) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305892/proof-of-similarity-between-well-ordered-sets). I have some trouble understanding the construction of the sequence function f below.

> We assume that X and Y are non-empty well ordered sets such that
> neither is similar to an initial segment of the other; we proceed to
> prove that under these circumstances X must be similar to Y. Suppose
> that $a \in X$ and that t is a sequence of type a in Y; in other words t is
> a function from s(a) into Y. Let f(t) be the least of the proper upper
> bounds of the range of t in Y, if there are any; ***in the contrary case***,
> let f(t) be the least element of Y.

(*s(a)* is the the initial segment of a in X)

My question is: *In what kind of sets does "the contrary case" occur?*

I've arrived at the conclusion that this will only happen if either Ran(t) has no upper bound or Ran(t) has only one upper bound $y \in Ran(t)$ due to X and Y both being well-ordered. But in the latter case, f wouldn't be one-to-one and X would (probably) not be similar to Y. I can't think of any set where Ran(t) doesn't have an upper bound. Can you help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, consider $X=Y=\{0,1\}$.  Take $a=1$ and define $t:s(a)\to Y$ by $t(0)=1$.  Then the image of $t$ has no strict upper bounds in $Y$, since $1$ is its largest element.